# Integration of Ckeditor with ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs, ckeditor

Is there a easy way to integrate Ckeditor with ExtJs 6 or 7. I try to follow some tutorials but without success.

Comment: There is quite a lot of work involved into getting HTML editors like this working with ExtJS because the main editor is inside of an iframe, so translating events and values from one document to another requires something tinkering with.
I'd give the new Froala editor a chance, will be available in ExtJS 7.

Comment: It is not easy, as @GuilhermeLopes said. It took me about one week to get it working with extJs6. Required a lot of research and building a custom package. Got it to work eventually.

Comment: After a lot of research, i found the Froala editor and i could integrate with EXT6.
Here(https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2upk) is a fiddle with a example.
Thank you all for the replies